# Movie intro before game start

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play m4v file before the game starts. The game is `cocos2d` based.

I made a `MPMoviePlayerController` with the required file and added it as child to `CCDirector` (which is a subclass of `UIViewController`). The reason why I am adding `MPMoviePlayerController` as child is that I want the game to keep loading in background.

My problem is that I am unable to find a way to remove the `MPMoviePlayerController` after the video finishes.

Please give suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but my first instinct is, could you just pop the view that contains the movie player, and have the menu system behind it, or whatever it is that you want to go to after the intro?

Comment: pop? but I am not pushing on navigation controller. I am adding as child of CCDirector (which is a subclass on viewcontroller) and to remove it I am trying removefromParentView....but not working

Answer (score 0):

For cocos2D game CCVideoPlayer class is best and easy to play video. [CLICK HERE FOR EXTENSION](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1641)

Comment: ya I do know about that...that will be perhaps the last solution :) thanks for suggestion anyways @raj

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification, then remove the subview. This code worked in my tests:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.player = moviePlayer;

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer play];

// wait for the video to finish...
MyViewController __weak *weakSelf = self;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:weakSelf name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:weakSelf.player];

  // remove the view
  [weakSelf.player.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to post your player creation and setup code for us to help you figure out what's going on.